# azure-event-hubs-for-kafka: EOF during handshake, handshake status is NEED_UNWRAP

Tags: java, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

i'm trying the azure-event-hubs-for-kafka quickstart java samples, and cannot get producer working, error message:

```
[Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Connection with <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/191.1.129.16 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: EOF during handshake, handshake status is NEED_UNWRAP
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:525)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:368)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-01-11 09:06:34 DEBUG SslTransportLayer:198 - [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=<my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/191.1.129.16:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@5603a6ad, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] Failed to send SSL Close message
```

here is my producer.config:

```
bootstrap.servers=<my_EH_namespace_here>.servicebus.windows.net:9093
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://<my_EH_namespace_here>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=xxxxxx;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxx";
```

apache kafka-clients: 3.0.1

here is the log from the run:

```
2023-01-11 09:05:49 INFO  KafkaProducer:532 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2023-01-11 09:05:49 INFO  AbstractLogin:61 - Successfully logged in.
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG DefaultSslEngineFactory:264 - Created SSL context with keystore null, truststore null, provider SunJSSE.
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG Sender:238 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG TransactionManager:1091 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Transition from state UNINITIALIZED to INITIALIZING
2023-01-11 09:05:49 INFO  AppInfoParser:119 - Kafka version: 3.0.1
2023-01-11 09:05:49 INFO  AppInfoParser:120 - Kafka commitId: 8e30984f43e64d8b
2023-01-11 09:05:49 INFO  AppInfoParser:121 - Kafka startTimeMs: 1673456749806
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG KafkaProducer:434 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Kafka producer started
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG TransactionManager:1129 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Enqueuing transactional request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1)
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG NetworkClient:1151 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Initialize connection to node <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG ClientUtils:113 - Resolved host <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net as 191.1.129.16
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG NetworkClient:980 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Initiating connection to node <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) using address <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/191.1.129.16
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG SaslClientAuthenticator:411 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Set SASL client state to SEND_APIVERSIONS_REQUEST
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG SaslClientAuthenticator:217 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Creating SaslClient: client=null;service=kafka;serviceHostname=<my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net;mechs=[PLAIN]
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG Selector:531 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2023-01-11 09:05:49 DEBUG NetworkClient:942 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
Test Data #0 from thread #20
2023-01-11 09:05:59 DEBUG SslTransportLayer:198 - [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=<my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/191.1.129.16:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl@5603a6ad, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] Failed to send SSL Close message
java.io.IOException: Unexpected status returned by SSLEngine.wrap, expected CLOSED, received OK. Will not send close message to peer.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:972)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:155)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:955)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:939)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:885)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleTimedOutConnections(NetworkClient.java:809)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:564)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-01-11 09:05:59 DEBUG NetworkClient:810 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Disconnecting from node -1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 9404 ms.
2023-01-11 09:05:59 WARN  NetworkClient:1054 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Bootstrap broker <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-01-11 09:05:59 DEBUG Sender:475 - [Producer clientId=KafkaExampleProducer] Disconnect from <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) while trying to send request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1). Going to back off and retry.
java.io.IOException: Connection to <my_EH_namespace>.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.awaitNodeReady(Sender.java:526)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.maybeSendAndPollTransactionalRequest(Sender.java:447)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: If you've followed event hubs documentation, I suggest contacting their support